# Transform a vec2 into another space

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, glsl

In a OpenGL fragment-shader, I need to transform a vec2 that represents a xy pair I need to another coordinate space.

I got the mat4 transformation-matrix for this, but can simply transform by:

`vec2 transformed = (tansformMat4 * vec4(xy, 0.0f)).xy` ?

I guess the result would not be correct, since the the 0s would get claculated into the x and y part.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in the fragment shader? Did you lookup the value you need to transform in a texture? Usually you'd be better off doing this sort of thing per-vertex in the vertex shader and using the interpolated result in the fragment shader.

Comment: I have to do it in the Fragment shader, since ist part of a bias calculation (Google "adaptive bias for shadow maps" if you're interested) for shadow mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4D vectors and Matrices are used for 3D Affine Transformations.

You can use the equivalent 2D Affine Transformation which is a 3D vector with the z-value to 1 (and then discarded):

```
vec3 transformed3d = transformMat3 * vec3(x, y, 1.0);
vec2 transformed2d(transformed3d.x, transformed3d.y);
```

Or alternatively, you can use can use the aforementioned 3D Affine Transformation with a 4D vector and Matrix by setting the z-value to zero and the w-value to 1 for homogeneous coordinates and then using the x and y values directly in a parallel projection:

```
vec4 transformed4d = transformMat4 * vec3(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
vec2 transformed2d(transformed4d.x, transformed4d.y);
```

Comment: Why would you set the z-value to 1.0 when using 3D vectors? Depending on the transformation, it may not matter, but it generally seems more natural to place 2D vectors on the z = 0.0 plane. The shader syntax in this answer is also overly complicated, and does not match the naming that the original poster used. If the poster only operates on 2D vectors, I would actually use `mat2` for the transformations.

Comment: On second thought, is your suggestion to use 3x3 matrices to represent affine transformations in 2D space? Then using 1.0 for z makes sense. But if that's the intention, you may want to elaborate on it, because it wasn't obvious at least to me.

Comment: @RetoKoradi See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_Coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations

Comment: thx for the answer. I am currently working with a parallel projection, but for the future, what would be the changes for projective projection?

Comment: @nurgan You would divide each component of vec4 transformed4d by its w-value before using the values.